# Two etherchannel in a switch

Tags: etherchannel

I configured two etherchannel in "switch 3" with LACP, however i cannot ping pc1 to pc0. they both are in same vlan and i configured in port-channel with "sw trunk allowed vlan all". but still i failed to ping.

commands used for configuring

```
int range fa 0/4-5
 channel-group 1 mode passive
!
int port-channel 1 
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 sw mode trunk
 sw trunk allowed vlan all"
```

### Port-channel of Switch 3

[image: Portchannel 1]

[image: Portchannel 2]

[![Running config][3]][3]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLIOb.jpg 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/WigIF.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDx5M.jpg

### Spanning tree of Switch 4

[image: Spanning treee]

### Spanning Tree of Switch 3

[image: Spanning tree of switch 3]

Comment: From your description is hard to understand where are devices connected and what is overall topology. Please provide simple schematic of your network topology. Also configuration of ports where end-devices connected to would be helpful.

Comment: Also what I can notice here, that another side of your port-channel (I believe this is another switch) should have ports configured in `active` mode, otherwise LACP neighborship would not be established.

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7Rgy.jpg

Comment: I did configure the other side as Active. everything was running but as soon as i ping the packet is not forwarded from S3 to S4

Comment: Can you share output of command `show etherchannel port-channel` from each switch?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLIOb.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WigIF.jpg

Comment: Please update your original post with switches configurations.

Comment: Type "show spanning-tree vlan <x>" on both switches.  Make sure only one is the root.

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Simply copy the text and paste it into your question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`). Also, put your configuration directly into the question, not through links.

Comment: I see no user ports on Sw 4 that are forwarding.    Make sure the port your PC is plugged into is configured for the right VLAN.  Also configure portfast on that port.

Comment: R.A. in order to help you we need full configurations of your switches. You can obviously remove all sensitive data such as passwords/usernames/etc. What you shared now is simply not enough.